# How to extract text from Selenium Object?

Tags: python, selenium

My code logs into my Fidelity account and then finds an element.  I'm able to find the Selenium object, but I want to extract the text in it which contains my portfolio balance.  When I print the object, the code works fine, but I'm unable to get the text or the balance from it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def fidelity_check():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    # options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Notebook\Documents\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.fidelity.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#userId-input"))).send_keys(
        "MYUSERID")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("MYPASSWORD")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#fs-login-button").click()

    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "tabContentSummary"]'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
        print(element_present)
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Page Not Loaded.")
```

This is the result:
selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located object at 0x035EFE10

Here is the inspect element results:

```html
<span class="ledger--section-total js-total-balance-value">$X.XX</span>
```

I tried the following and it doesn't work.

```py
element_present.text()
# And I tried:
element_present.text
```

Neither work.

Comment: Have you tried `element_present.innerHTML`?

Comment: Can you please provide complete DOM ?

Comment: @Arn, I just tried it and it didn't work.  I just edited it for the whole code.  Maybe calling it my XPATH isn't the right way since I can't use the .text or .innerHTML methods.

Comment: @Rock, I just posted the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try below solution

```
amount = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id = "tabContentSummary"]//span')))
print(amount.text)
```

Comment: another person posted before with a similar variation.  It works perfectly.  The program calls it too quickly, so it says Loading...instead of the balance.  I need to delay a little.   Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the value in a variable from `WebDriverWait` and then get the text.What you have done you have printed selenium object.

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "tabContentSummary"]'))
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(element_present)
print(element.text)
```

`EDIT`:

```
element_present = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "tabContentSummary"]'))
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(element_present)
print(element.text)
```

OR

```
element_present = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '// *[ @ id = "tabContentSummary"]'))
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(element_present)
print(element.text)
```

Comment: this worked!!  It returned Loading... because my computer is quick, so I just need to delay it a little until the balance is shown.  Thanks so much for the reply.

Comment: @BrandonJacobson : Can you check edited option.I believe you dont need to add delay using my Edited option.Give it a try.